# C++ and Sfml Inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, sfml

**How can I use the dynamic variable by inherited. Sample;**

```
 class car
{
public:
    car();
    sf::Vector2f whereİsCar();
    void event(); //veryLong code = change spriteCar Position

protected:
  sf::Sprite spriteCar;

};

car::car()
{

    spriteCar.setPosition(300, 10);


}
car::Update()
{

    cout << spriteCar.position.x; << " " << spriteCar.position.y; // example Console : 550 210


}

class Rocket : public car

{

public:

    Rocket();
    void collideCar();
    void update();

private:
    sf::Sprite spriteRocket;

}

void Rocket::collideCar()
{

  cout << spriteCar.position.x; << " " << spriteCar.position.y; // Console : 300 10
}
```

When i run my game,changing values ​​in a class does not change the class b.

How do i fix it.

I hope understand me.
Thank you for helping.

Comment: could you make a clean version of your code ? And describe in one or two sentences what should be happening ?

Comment: Then, could you give it a proper indentation ?
Could you put a little piece of the code making use of class a or class b ?

Comment: why does rocket::collideCar does the same thing as car::Update, whithout even calling it ? is it normal that car::Update and rocket::update writings differ ? I guess the code that runs everything must be like a loop calling event then Update on a rocket or on a car, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Because I suppose you are using two different objects.

```
Car car();
Rocket rocket();
car.event() //spriteCar's position changed inside car object. Not relevant to rocket object.
```

You are using inheritance wrong. You can pass a reference to rocket object to use in it.

Maybe you may want to share your main code with us.

Comment: i do but i was say its very long code. 
i want use dynamic position carSprite (sf::vector2f) ,i use rocket class. but the rocket class always same.Not change car position in rocket class. Sorry my bad english.

Comment: No problem. Can I see your main function at least only relevant codes to rocket and car?